# How to put through my idea?

Tags: discussion

I read this topic and several answers here [Create a world where Necromancy isn't considered as an "evil" type of magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/75416/create-a-world-where-necromancy-isnt-considered-as-an-evil-type-of-magic?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

And one idea crossed my mind: Why necessarily make it bad or good? There were ideas to resurrect only humans, that were sinful in their lives. And so, why not do it as some kind of karma thing. When you resurrect/reanimate someone, who was honest and good in life, you will get "bad karma", and when you reanimate someone bad, you will get "good karma", or at least you won't get more bad karma. Details are unimportant, the concept is. So, actually, it would be the player's choice, whether necromancy in that world would be perceived as rigidly evil or can be seen as something kind of acceptable, or something like that.

I have not seen such proposal among answers to that question, if someone could post it there, I would be very thankful. I can't, since I don't post here much and there is some reputation required to post an answer. I think it is not a bad idea and I do not desire credit for it, just want to offer another way of thinking about that problem. And I apologize for my English, not my first language.

Comment: If you post an answer on a question that is not protected and get an upvote you will receive the 10 reputation that are required. You can also suggest edits to get 2 reputation each and an upvote on a question of yours is worth 5 reputation. You will surely get the 10 reputation in no time. Have fun on the site!

Comment: And I want to add that it's very nice of you to try adding something to the question, even if you cannot do it yourself right now. I hope you stick around and provide answers to more questions. Have fun!

Answer (score 7):

Question you want to answer is protected, because it attracted too much low quality ideas. Sorry it hit you, but before you start earning your reputation we can't know if your ideas are usually solid, or ill defined and low quality.

Just find something else, and answer. Worldbuilding is broad, soft and fluid discipline of art. All you need is one upvote. Shouldn't be hard to get. Or ask a well defined on topic question. Two upvotes and you are not the newbie protection is designed to work against. This meta question shows you can write something good enough. So just do it - but start in less exposed place, under less exciting question.